# How to join between two PBX telephones wirelessly?

Tags: telecommunication, wireless-communication, consumer-electronics

I have two [PBX telephones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_telephone_system). Each one has a line cables to the houses, but there is no connection between these two pbx telephones, neither wire nor wireless. How can I join between them wirelessly? What equipment should I buy?

Comment: Are there any Atas that have many telephone jacks, because I need them for Business

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible answers. In your place I did the following:

1. I would buy 2 [analog telephone voip adapters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_telephone_adapter) (at most some tens of dollars). Putting them to the phones, from now you have IP connection.
2. Buy two [wireless routers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_router) (some tens of dollars). Connect them with static IP addresses and routes.
3. Optionally, if you also don't have power, then you can buy [solar panels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_panel) (thousands of dollars) and a [UPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply) (hundreds of dollars). But the first is costly, maybe a mechanical battery charger would be significantly cheaper (some hundred dollars).

The whole thing would cost around some hundreds dollars if you don't have power, but yo can solve this even below \$100 if you have.

The main disadvantage of this system is that the range of the wireless router is short.

Comment: I am sorry for this IT-oriented answer, this was the best on my knowledge level. Maybe this question had a better place on SU or on networkengineering SE.